# php/MySQL INSERT executing twice

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried various ways like object and non-object, and multiple examples around the web. I know this has been asked before, but for some reason nothing has solved my issue. I've done plenty of INSERTS in the past and have never ran into this problem before.

I just want to log ip addresses and referral urls to help fight against adwords fraud/sabotage, but for some reason it's being executed twice. The first time, the referral is blank and the second time the referring url is itself.

Here is the current code I'm using:

```
$db = 'defensalegal';
$table = 'dogbite_tracker';

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

$conn->query('INSERT INTO '.$table.' (ID, ip, views, timestamp, referer) VALUES("", "'.$ip.'", "1", "'.date('Y-m-d').' @ '.date('H:i:s').'", "'.$referer.'")');
$conn->close();
```

I've verified it's not a refresh issue since it does it when you directly type in the url as well, and I also wiped the entire file of everything except the above code snippet in case there was some sort of conflict happening, still got duplicate inserts.

I'm not getting any errors as either.

Comment: Looks to me like your script is probably executing twice. Have you tried logging at the top of your script and seeing if the log appears twice?

Comment: for quick fix, create unique index with ip, timestamp, referer. You just need to run a single command on your SQL server.

Comment: Try something like [debug_print_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) to see, why it is executed twice.

Comment: @AmericanUmlaut are you referring to `console.log()` in js?

Comment: I tried using an `echo` before and after the SQL statement, and it only printed out once. I'm kinda at a loss as to what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

The quick fix would be

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_ip_timestamp_referer ON dogbite_tracker(ip, timestamp, referer);
```

This is quick solution of your problem, run this query on your DB server (SQL Console)

For exact solution, You need to post your full script (Code).

Comment: did you checked your unique indexes define in your DB, see that first and see the fields are bind for index or not. check syntax for creating unique field based on your table column . this must work because i had similar problem and i did this ....see creating unique index with multiple column in mysql

Answer (score -2):

Looks like your script is doable to make duplicate insert, as stated previously to make unique index your script should
    1. Check if previous ip already on database
    2. Update the ip if exists
    3. Insert new if ip not exists